# How is heapq.heappushpop more efficient than heappop and heappush in python

Tags: python-3.x, heap

In the docs for heapq, its written that

> heapq.heappushpop(heap, item)
>
> > Push item on the heap, then pop and return the smallest item from the heap. The combined action runs more efficiently than heappush() followed by a separate call to heappop().

Why is it more efficient? 
Also is it considerably more efficient ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `heappop` is pop out the first element, then move the last element to fill the in the first place, then do a sinking operation, which moving the the element down through consecutive exchange. thus restore the head
  it is `O(logn)`
  then you `headpush`, place the element in the last place, and bubble-up 
  like `heappop` but reverse
  another `O(logn)`
- while `heappushpop`, pop out the first element, instead of moving the last element to the top, it place the new element in the top, then do a sinking motion. which is almost the same operation with `heappop`.
  just one `O(logn)`

as above even though they are both `O(logn)`, it is easier to see `heappushpop` is faster than `heappop` then `heappush`.

Comment: Something to mention is that in python, when calling `heappop` you will make a copy of the list (to 1 of 1 length smaller) which you can argue shouldn't be that inefficient since it will only be copying the references (but imo is a bit expensive). Then you will call `heapush` which will make another copy of the list (back to the previous length). I am not familiar with the CPython implementation for this, but I would suppose there is some optimization for this.

For `heapushpop` no copying of the list needs to be made.

Answer (score 2):

heappushpop pushes an element and then pops the smallest elem. If the elem you're pushing is smaller than the heap's minimum, then there's no need to do any operations., because we know that the element we're trying to push (which is smaller than the heap min), will be popped if we do it in two operations.

This is efficient, isn't it?